# Make the whole div sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem , where I can't find the answer on.

I have a div , where the data comes from a database. (loop)

I try to make the div's sortable.(The whole div (not a part of it)

(that i can move the whole div to another row)

I searched for answer and tried:

https://jqueryui.com/sortable/

[jquery .sortable() on <div>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9659966/jquery-sortable-on-div) (i think this is the answer but couldn't fix it)

[jQuery UI sortable divs across multiple containers or parents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574274/jquery-ui-sortable-divs-across-multiple-containers-or-parents)

even the drag and drop of the jquery ui

https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-helper

```js
    $(".Regel").sortable({
    });
```

```html
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

<div class="Regel">
  <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick" ></span>
   <div><input size="23" maxlength="250"></div>
   <div><input size="23" maxlength="50" ></div>
   <div><input name="Links_Omschrijving" size="23" maxlength="100"></div>

   <div>
    <select>
     <option value="VerkoopAankoop">Something</option>
     <option>Onething</option>
     <option >AnotherThing</option>
    </select>
   </div>
 </div> 
  
  <br><br>
  
  <div class="Regel">
  <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick" ></span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wPtjM/4/ tried but failed

https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/

https://jsfiddle.net/ramnathv/1064q7jm/

and tried many more.

I changed my div to create an jsfiddle and made 2 of the same div

I use in my code sortable (I think is the wrong method, but everything i could find)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wPtjM/4/
-
http://jsfiddle.net/wPtjM/1/
-
https://jsfiddle.net/ramnathv/1064q7jm/

tried this too

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. Can you tell me what kind of behavior do you expect and which JSFIDDLE is your current setup?

Comment: I whant to be able to sort the whole div with another div. @Rotan075

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply you can use parent div for make whole div sortable.

```js
$(".Regel").parent().sortable({});
  //OR  $("#container").sortable({});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<div id="container">
    <div class="Regel">
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick" ></span>
     <div><input size="23" maxlength="250"></div>
  <div><input size="23" maxlength="50" ></div>
  <div><input name="Links_Omschrijving" size="23" maxlength="100"></div>
  <div>
      <select>
       <option value="VerkoopAankoop">Something</option>
    <option>Onething</option>
    <option >AnotherThing</option>
   </select>
  </div>
 </div> 
  
  <br><br>
  
  <div class="Regel">
  <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick" ></span>
     AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
  </div>
  <div class="Regel">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick" ></span>
    BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
  </div>
```

Comment: THNXXXXX !!! it worked (it was just 1 line where i searched whole week for answer :(

Comment: Welcome.. its my pleasure.. :) dont forget to mark as correct and up vote also.